# Why does my computer perform much worse on dx11 than dx9

Tags: crysis-2

The games I noticed it on was crysis 2 and L.A. Noire
It will give me this weird like mouse lag where its really delayed and it plays much worse.

Specs:
Processor=Intel i5 4690k

GPU=XFX Radeon R9 290X
DirectX 11.2 R9-290X-8DFD 8GB 512-Bit DDR5 PCI Express 3.0 Double Dissipation Edition

Comment: Probably because the games that are running on dx11 are more resource intensive

Comment: Both of those games are DX9 games, so you have DX9 installed, which means your not using DX11

Answer (score 3):

**DirectX 9** was mainly intended for use on Windows Vista and windows 7 machines, and the technology available at the time.

When those operating systems were released, you often saw "Gaming PC's" with dual-core processors, 8GB of RAM, 1GB of VRAM, and so on. DirecX9 was specifically catered to look best, while performing the best on these generation of computers.

**DirectX 11** was released instead on the next two generations of Operating Systems, Windows 8, and Windows 10.

Windows 8 was a nightmare to check email on, let alone try to run a game such as Crysis.

Windows 10 was, however, done a massively amount better, in nearly all aspects.

The Windows 8 and Windows 10 generation of PC's had specs, often including Quad-Core processors, 16GB of RAM, and 4GB of VRAM.

DirectX 11 was catered to these new specifications.

When your computer is lacking in one or more of the critical areas, DX11 will often fail your expectations.

*TL;DR, DX11 has great quality images, but DX9 is built to be less power-hungry.*

**Now, as for the i5.** I have a few machines with i5 quad core processors in them. I also have a few with i7's.

The i5 was great for its' time, however, intel never did nail down the mutli-threading on multiple cores on the i5 like they did with the i7, and they're still screwing in a few loose nuts and bolts.

Often, either system services, the CPU, or the device itself will cause this input lag - some game settings may as well.

***SUPER*** TL;DR, Your PC isn't up to par to run DX11 smoothly. I suggest you sacrifice some of the glorious graphics, and tone back down to DX9.